# how to pass dynamic string array from javascript to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

```
function createNew(mouseEventData) {
 var measurementData = {
            visible: true,
            active: true,
            toolType: 'target',
            description: output
        };

        return measurementData;
}

 function onImageRendered(e, eventData) {
    var textline = ["Test"];
    var obj = { "description":textline};
    alert(obj)//[object Object]
    var output = JSON.stringify(obj);
    alert("output"+output); //output{"description":["Test"]}
}
```

In the above snippet, I want to pass the textline string array to description field of measurementData.
Please help me on how to pass dynamic string array to JSON object
(the textline is dynamic array)

Comment: "how to pass dynamic string array to JSON object". You're already doing that (at least to the `obj`, if not the `measurementData` object). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If it is then from where are you getting this?  Also, what is `eventData`?

Comment: function addNew(mouseEventData) {
        var measurementData = createNew(mouseEventData);

        var eventData = {
            mouseButtonMask: mouseEventData.which,
        };
 }

Comment: Are you talking about wanting to 'subscribe' to the changes to `textline`. Updating the json string when it's value changes? Else i'm not sure what you mean by 'dynamic', you are passing the value of `textline` into the json in that snippet.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the JSON to the object? Why not pass the object itself? And why pass `eventData` to `createNew` if you're not going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a global variable:

```
var measurementData;

function createNew(mouseEventData) {
    return measurementData;
}

function onImageRendered(e, eventData) {
    var textline = ["Test"];
    measurementData = {
        visible: true,
        active: true,
        toolType: 'target',
        description: textline
    };
}
```